# Why auto deduces a reference object instead of bool for std::bitset::operator []

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset

I have the following code

```
std::bitset<32> bs{21};
auto ref_obj = bs[0];
auto &another_ref = bs[0];
bool bool_obj = bs[0];
```

The type of `ref_obj` is not `bool`. But `another_ref` has the same type as `ref_obj`. `std::bitset::operator[]` has 3 overloads listed at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at

But I could not figure out why it is so.

Comment: Look at overload 2 (`reference operator[]( std::size_t pos );`).  Your object is not `const`.

Comment: yes. I think that is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++11 standard, if your bitset is not `const` (and yours isn't), then a reference type is returned:

§20.6.2 bitset operations:

```
constexpr bool operator[](size_t pos) const; // for b[i];
reference operator[](size_t pos); // for b[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

The minimum addressable type in C++ is *a byte* which is presumably to be *at least 8 bits* [[intro.memory/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro#memory-1). Hence there is no way to return a reference to a single *bit* (which is less than 1 byte). So when you need a reference to that, a proxy that does some black magic is returned.

Your object isn't `const`, hence it is assumed you may want to modify the element through the via the `[]` operator. You can cast it to a `const` reference and access the `const` qualified member overload.